# Android Studio Button remove shadow outside radius borders

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, button, shadow

In my project, I have buttons on my homepage:
[said buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry60E.png)

however im trying to remove the shadow from the buttons, which you can see in the bottom corners.

The buttons are added to the homepage with kotlin but i think that is unimported for this problem.

my button xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="0sp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mainButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/grid_button_template"
            android:text="Event Name\n\n00/00/0000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

and the @drawable/grid_button_template"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    <padding
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp" />

</shape>
```

how do i remove those shaddows. I have already tried setting the elevation but that didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add this property.

```
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
```

Please let me know if it works at your side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CardView` attributes to have the rounded corners. Doing that, you no longer need the `@drawable/grid_button_template`. Here's how it can be done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#55FF0000"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mainButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:text="Event Name\n\n00/00/0000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```